# How to target the second to last child's child?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML like this

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#1"></a>
    </li>
    <div></div>
    <li>
        <a href="#2"></a>
    </li>
    <div></div>
    <li>
        <a href="#3"></a>
    </li>
    <div></div>
    <li>
        <a href="#4"></a>
    </li>
    <div></div>
</ul>
```

I want to target the last link (#4) and store it into a variable called tab. Here's what I wrote but I know it's wrong

```
var tab = $(".menu").is(":nth-last-child(2)").children().attr("href");
```

Comment: that's not valid html anyways. you can't have a naked `<div>` inside a `<ul>` like that.

Comment: I know I should have structured it differently but I stuck using it for now

Comment: is the second to last child always an `li` and thats child always  an `a` tag?

Comment: yes, it will always be <li> with a child of <a> followed by a <div>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the anchor of the second to last child, do

```
var children = $('.menu').children();
var childCount = $('.menu').children().length;
var secondToLast = children[childCount - 2];

var anchor = $(secondToLast).find('[href]');
var href = anchor.attr('href');
```

```js
var children = $('.menu').children();
var childCount = $('.menu').children().length;
var secondToLast = children[childCount - 2];

var anchor = $(secondToLast).find('[href]');
var href = anchor.attr('href');
console.log(href);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#1"></a>
    </li>
    <div></div>
    <li>
        <a href="#2"></a>
    </li>
    <div></div>
    <li>
        <a href="#3"></a>
    </li>
    <div></div>
    <li>
        <a href="#4"></a>
    </li>
    <div></div>
</ul>
```

Otherwise, if you want the last anchor regardless do

```
var lastAnchor = $('a:last');
var href = lastAnchor.attr('href');
```

```js
var lastAnchor = $('a:last');
var href = lastAnchor.attr('href');
console.log(href);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#1"></a>
  </li>
  <div></div>
  <li>
    <a href="#2"></a>
  </li>
  <div></div>
  <li>
    <a href="#3"></a>
  </li>
  <div></div>
  <li>
    <a href="#4"></a>
  </li>
  <div></div>
</ul>
```

Comment: So which one sould I use to store in a variable that grabs the second to last anchor tag's href, that is contained in the ul class of '.menu'?

Comment: @RobbieFikes, is your HTML dynamic? Or do you always want to target `<a href="#3"></a>`?

Comment: Dynamic, so there could be more in the list with the same structure, I just chose to do it 3 times

Comment: Put the question another way, do you always want to grab second to last regardless? Btw, in your example above `<a href="#3"></a>` is not second to last

Comment: Actually I mean the last <a>. Which happens to be the second to the last child's child

Comment: @RobbieFikes, see my updated answer and let me know if you meant something else

Answer (score 1):

This will select the 2nd to last `li` element's `a` tag

`$('.menu').find('li:nth-last-child(2) a')`

if theres more than one `a` tag per `li`, you can specify which `a` child you want by adding an `nth-child` to the a. for instance, to grab the first `a` tag withing the 2nd-to-last `li` you would use:

`$('.menu').find('li:nth-last-child(2) a:nth-child(1)')`

heres a fiddle demonstrating the selection by modifying the background color

https://jsfiddle.net/779zynLv/